# Rails/Oracle: ActiveRecord find returning different results from console and app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord

I recently started moving my application from using sqlite to Oracle and began experiencing the following issue:

With rails 3.2.13, Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 and activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.2), I have the following in my controller:

```
def show
    if params.has_key?('user_id')
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    else
      @user = current_user
    end
    @user_id = @user.id

    @activity_date = Date.parse(params[:id])
    #@activity_date = Activity.all.first.activity_date

    @activities = Activity.where("user_id = ? AND activity_date = ?", @user.id, @activity_date)
    logger.warn "----- count is #{@activities.count} ------"
return
```

- The application ***finds exactly 0 records*** (as per the logger output and with the appropriate values for @user and @activity_date).
- development.log reports the generated query as:

  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "ACTIVITIES" WHERE (user_id = 10594 AND to_date(activity_date) = TO_DATE('2013-06-05','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))

and if I run this query from SQL*Plus, I get exactly 4 records - ***which I am expecting*.**
 - so it appears there is a discrepancy between the results returned by AR and the results returned by the query AR is reporting to my log.

- further, if I muck around and manually set the date before the where call with something like

  @activity_date = Activity.all.first.activity_date

where the first activity date happens to be the "correct" activity date, Rails returns all 4 rows, so the console and app are pointing to the same database.

As far as I can tell:

- Rails is generating a valid query, so the values going into the .where method are OK
- said query returns the "right" number of results, *when run from SQL*Plus*
- the console and the application are pointing to the same databases
- but Rails seems to be "seeing" the wrong number of results.

What's going on ? I'm running out of hair to pull out.

**EDIT** Removed TO_DATE call around activity_date placeholder as per David Aldridge's suggestion below; still don't get the right result set.
**EDIT** As per David's suggestion:

```
 @user_id=10594
 @activity_date=Date.parse('2013-06-13')

####### **Returned wrong set of results**
####### Note class of @activity_date is Date
    bundler-0.9.24 :083 > @activity_date.class
    => Date 

    bundler-0.9.24 :084 > Activity.where("user_id = ? AND activity_date = ?", @userid, @activity_date).explain
      Activity Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "ACTIVITIES".* FROM "ACTIVITIES" WHERE (user_id = NULL AND activity_date = TO_DATE('2013-06-13','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
      EXPLAIN (7.8ms)  EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT "ACTIVITIES".* FROM "ACTIVITIES" WHERE (user_id = NULL AND activity_date = TO_DATE('2013-06-13','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))

####### **Returned right set of results**
    bundler-0.9.24 :089 > @activity_date=Activity.all.first.activity_date
      Activity Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "ACTIVITIES".* FROM "ACTIVITIES" 
    => Wed, 05 Jun 2013 04:00:00 UTC +00:00 

#### Note class of @activity_date is different from above**

    bundler-0.9.24 :090 > @activity_date.class
    => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone 
    bundler-0.9.24 :091 > Activity.where("user_id = ? AND activity_date = ?", @userid, @activity_date).explain
**And note generated query includes a time specification whereas previous query did not**
      Activity Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "ACTIVITIES".* FROM "ACTIVITIES" WHERE (user_id = NULL AND activity_date = TO_DATE('2013-06-05 04:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

**SOLVED**
When I was creating the activity_date field, I used Date.civil.  I neglected to consider that what Oracle calls its "Date" type actually contains a Time component as well.

Since Date.civil does not take time zones, the activity_date I stored is essentially a DateTime, *offset by the local timezone* (since Date.civil does not take time zones).  Since my application ignores the actual times, I solved this by computing the activity_date using DateTime.civil instead of Date.civil.   Thanks to David Aldridge for his help, and apologies that I don't have enough rep to upvote him for it.

Comment: I have noticed that Activity.all.first.activity_date is of class "ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone" (which works), whereas Date.parse returns an object of class Date (which does not seem to work)....

Comment: What does the query look like when you submit a TimeWithZone value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the activity_date column actually a date, or is it a character string that needs to be converted to a date?

If the former then the to_date is misplaced, and should not be present.

```
@activities = Activity.where("user_id = ? AND activity_date = ?", @user.id, @activity_date)
```

The reason why it might work in one environment and not the other is that the environments have different values for nls_date_parameter, either for the database or for the session.

A useful diagnostic here might be the explain plan, which should show implicit data conversions if rails is using DBMS_XPlan to get the plan. You should be able to get the plan through the console with:

```
Activity.where("user_id = ? AND activity_date = ?", @user.id, @activity_date).explain
```

Running the query in SQL*Plus and then running:

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

... ought to give you the plan that SQL*Plus is using.

If you post them in the question it might help future problem-encounterers.

Comment: The activity_date column is of type date.  I tried things both ways - wrapping and not wrapping the activity_date placeholder in a TO_DATE call, and it does not appear to make any difference: both ways returns the same set of results.  Thank you David.

Comment: Does it make a difference to the query? How about if you supply the predicates as where(:user_id => @user_id, :activity_date => @activity_date) ...?

Comment: If that makes no difference can you please try to pull the explain plans and post them? It will reveal any query transformations that the optimiser is applying, or any expansions in the to_date conversion format pictures.

Comment: David - I stand corrected.  Removing the TO_DATE call does indeed make a difference to the query, but I (still) get nothing back (I think this is how I wrote it the first time).  Supplying the predicates as you suggest does not change the query generated, nor the results I get back, either.  I have noticed that Activity.all.first.activity_date (which does work) returns a different class than Date.parse - and am wondering whether that is where my problem might lie.

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious about the to_date() that activerecord creates, in which the data itself is YYYY-MM-DD but the date format picture includes a time component. I've tested this though, and it seems to be OK. Is there possibly a time component of activity_date?

Comment: This was the problem.  When I create the Activity record I was using Date.civil.  However, I neglected to consider that  Oracle's "Date" type actually contains a date component, so when I thought I was storing only a date, Oracle was storing a Date with time.  Hence, the Date I stored is essentially a DateTime, offset by the local timezone (since Date.civil does not take time zones).  Since my application ignores the actual times, I solved this by computing the activity_date using DateTime.civil instead of Date.civil.   Thanks much for your help David.